# DAC to ADC errors

Tags: adc, dac, error

I am testing my setup of [MCP4725](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/MCP4725.pdf) DAC connected to [MCP3221](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001732E.pdf) ADC. DAC's output is connected to ADC's input. I'm measuring the difference between set values in DAC and measured values in ADC and I'm getting these strange patterns.[image]
Edit:x axis: values set in DAC (bits), y axis: DAC value - ADC value (bits)

Minimums and maximums are repeating every 128 bits. Also, errors shift from positive to negative going through the full range. I have tried different delays between setting DAC value and measuring ADC value and I get the same result. So I think it is not background noise.

Edit2:Schematics:
[image]

I use [REF3033](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbvs131/sbvs131.pdf) to power both ADC and DAC. But the same pattern is present when connecting them to [LF33CV](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/c4/0e/7e/2a/be/bc/4c/bd/CD00000546.pdf/files/CD00000546.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000546.pdf). Also, adding additional capacitors betwen input/output and ground doesn't change the pattern, just shifts it up or down.

Could you please help me figure out why is this happening and how to avoid it?
I'm really sorry if this is something basic I'm missing here.

Comment: Take a good multimeter and measure the voltages for values with just one bit set

Comment: What range of different delays?

Comment: @PlasmaHH unfortunately I don't have a good multimeter on hand . However, measuring one bit with my ADC I see max 2 bit oscilations, so it doesn't explain the pattern.

Comment: @Trevor_G from 10ms to 500ms

Comment: As long as you figured out the cyclical pattern, and it is a power of 2, I believe the issue is rather in design of DAC or ADC, having some non-linearity when it comes to the values in bits above bit 7. The fact that graph goes down between the peaks makes me think that designers *know* about this non-linearity, and try to compensate it this way.

Comment: Link to datasheets, and ideally a schematic may help to identify weaknesses. There are some DAC architectures prone to errors of this form (and  there's a DAC inside most ADCs) but not usually this magnitude unless something else is wrong. Check power supplies, reference voltage source impedances, and source impedance driving the ADC. And note the main slope indicates a DC offset and a gain error.

Comment: Are you using some bypass caps?

Comment: @BrianDrummond, thank you for your insights. I added schematics and some more information about power source.
I'm quite a begginer in electronics, so I don't know how to find out the source impedance of my voltage source. Maybe scehmatics and datasheets will help you figure it out.

Comment: @Chupacabras I have tried adding additional caps to the power supply and to ADC output, but it didn't remove the pattern.

Comment: DAC datasheet page 3 says output impedance  is 1 ohm which is fine. BUT ...page 2 says "INL Error (max) +/-14.5 LSBs". This is pretty appalling. Your plot shows about +/-4 LSBs, double the "Typical" spec on same page but much less than the guaranteed max. Also see Fig 2.5 p.5, same basic pattern (in some ways worse). That might be all you get unless you use a better DAC. (update : ADC spec looks OK)

Comment: @BrianDrummond, thanks a lot! That answers my question! Guess I will have to look for a better DAC or compensate for the errors in code.

Comment: And now you know to read the INL and DNL specs before putting down your money.

Comment: @BrianDrummond please make your comment an answer, and elaborate what all this means :)

Comment: @BrianDrummond already ordered DAC7571, seems much better.

Answer (score 7):

DAC output voltage accuracy can be estimated by looking at the data sheet and the output error limits: -

[image]

Then you need to understand what terms like INL mean: -

[image]

The graph above shows INL (integral non-linearity). Basically, it means that the DAC output could have to +/- 14.5 least significant bits of error from the ideal straight line. Given your DAC is 12 bits (4096 LSBs), the INL produces an error of +/- 0.35%.

But you will also have a zero and a gain error: -

[image]

The gain error can be up to 2% of full-scale and the offset error can be up to 0.75% of full-scale.

You can also get an understanding on the error patterns if you delve deaper into the data sheet. For instance this graph on page 5 shows the effect of INL and notice how certain patterns repeat as per the picture in the question: -

[image]

Remember also this is just the DAC - a similar picture will exist for the ADC.